# Health check issue when deploying rails application on Digital Ocean using 1 click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-7, health-check

I attempted to deploy a Rails API application using 1 Click Ruby on Rails option on digital ocean but each time I try to deploy the application I get a health check error.

The build stage is successful:

[image: successful build stage]

But it fails when it gets to the deployment stage and there are no details on this error in the logs.

[image: health check error on deploy]

I tried checking the error logs but instead the server appears to be running.

[image: no specific details on the error]

What i have tried so far:

- Switched between the scheduled HTTP or TCP under health check in digital ocean.
  [image: Switched between the schedules]
- Confirmed if the droplet is live:

[image: droplet is live]

Used the rails build pack to create a new application in the droplet:

**::: Current build pack::::**
Custom Build Command v0.1.2
Procfilev 0.0.4
Ruby: v1.244.3
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Setup the correct environment variables for the app on the digital ocean console.

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=..correct key ommited deliberately..
RACK_ENV=development
RAILS_ENV=development
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE=key correct ommited deliberately..
```

In addition,I am currently on the basic plan which should allow me to deploy a rails application and i also tried setting the app level environment variables but they are were overriden by the env i initially setup when creating a new app.

[image]

**My setup:**

- Ruby and Rails versions:

  ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin20]
  Rails 7.1.3
- platform configs in gemfile:

  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
  group :development, :test do
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  end (edited)

The [App Platform Error Code Reference](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/reference/error-codes/) stipulates that this issue is caused by *

> the container not responding to health checks. If a health check is
> failing, that means that external traffic is not reaching my service
> at the expected HTTP route

*.How do ensure external traffic is reaching my service to resolve this if this is the solution?

Comment: The rails/ruby versions shown in the "Confirmed if the droplet is live" browser check don't match the deployed versions. I don't think you're checking what you think you're checking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Smathy.
Seems like the rails version on the droplet is different from the rails on puma on digital ocean.The droplet is indicating rails  is 7.0.4.2 and the application is using rails 7.1.3.Are you suggesting this could be the issue causing health checks to fail?

Comment: I dunno, just seemed funky but mostly I didn't want you relying on your check in the browser, because obviously that's looking at a different server than the one that's failing the health check.

Comment: I totally agree,Thank you.I decided to check my environment variables and it turns out I had some additional unnecessary variables that I removed and the application deployed with no errrors.
Now i just need to figure out why the api routes have issues.But the health check issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by updating my environment variables by removing `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled` and `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and then changed the `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` from development to production.

The application deployed successfully.Health check error resolved.

[image]

**Before**

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=..correct key ommited deliberately..
RACK_ENV=development
RAILS_ENV=development
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE=key correct ommited deliberately..
```

**Updated**

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=..correct key ommited deliberately..
RACK_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled
```